# How to remove double quotes from a nested list

Tags: python

I have a list  Let's say

```
m = [["'ghvghvgh hgdghdh', 'hxjhsdhb.com - Error 404:validation', 'jhhscbhjbcsd', 'hghs'"],["'ghvh', 'hxjhsdhb', 'jhhcsd', 'hs'"]]
```

and I want my output something like this (removing the double quotes).

````
m = [['ghvghvgh hgdghdh', 'hxjhsdhb.com - Error 404:validation', 'jhhscbhjbcsd', 'hghs'],['ghvh', 'hxjhsdhb', 'jhhcsd', 'hs']] ```

m[0][0].replace('"', '') # I have tried this
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To normalise the data, you need to replace the single quotes and not the double-ones the trim away extra spaces.

```py
lst = [
    i[0].replace("'", '').strip().split(', ') 
    for i in m
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, very much appreciated. Sorry, I made a mistake while posting, the list something like this
```m = [["'ghvghvgh', 'hxjhsdhb', 'jhhscbhjbcsd', 'hghs' "],[" 'ghvh', 'hxjhsdhb', 'jhhcsd', 'hs'"]]
```
There is no spacing between the double and single quotes

Comment: Did you test? This seems to output exactly the desired results even after your edits.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re 
a=re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+')
m = [["'ghvghvgh', 'hxjhsdhb', 'jhhscbhjbcsd', 'hghs' "],[" 'ghvh', 'hxjhsdhb', 'jhhcsd', 'hs'"]]
res= [[a.findall(i) for i in j][0] for j in m]
print(res)
```

output

```
[['ghvghvgh', 'hxjhsdhb', 'jhhscbhjbcsd', 'hghs'], ['ghvh', 'hxjhsdhb', 'jhhcsd', 'hs']]
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant, that worked like a charm and now I have updated my query. What do you think, what is the best approach for this scenario ?

Comment: @SAMARDUBEY use `a=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z ]+')` IN THIS case